# Difficulty reading a Bar Plot

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart

I am trying to learn some relation between the variables in my dataset. 
About the dataset: It is a real estate dataset and I am trying to see factors affecting the price based on location. 
However when i plot any graph it appears almost unreadable. I also tried to increase the graph size but doesnt help. Have attached the screenshot that has code and output. Please help..[barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGuWK.png)

code:

```
data['price'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
plt.title('price')
plt.xlabel('price')
plt.ylabel('longitude')
sns.despine
#change figure size
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10,6)
```

Comment: Your x-axis labels are printing on top of each other.  You need to print fewer of them, so they're spaced out enough to read.  MatPlot docs will show you how to specify equally-spaced labels as taken from a range you supply, or the specify otherwise.  At the moment, you seem to be printing the price of *every* property in the data set.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the correlation between the two variables, price, and longitude, I recommend a 2d histogram.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.hist2d(x=data['price'], y=data['longitude'],bins=50, cmin=1);
plt.grid(True);
plt.xlabel('Price', fontsize=16);
plt.ylabel('Longitude',fontsize=16);
```